# How to install KDE Plasma-Desktop on Arch-Linux-ARM?

Tags: archlinux, gui, desktop

**H!@all**
I have already installed Xorg "xf86-video-fbdev".
**pacman -S sddm** and **pacman -S plasma-desktop**, gives me five options for **SDDM** and the same five options for **Plasma-Desktop**:

```
1) libglvnd 2) imx-gpu-viv-dfb  3) imx-gpu-viv-fb  4) imx-gpu-viv-wl  5) imx-gpu-viv-x11
```

Which option is right one for the Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB)?

Answer (score 1):

`libglvnd` should work. You can ask in the [Arch Linux arm forum](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/) if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: **libglvnd** is already installed.

Comment: @Teso I meant you should select the first option libglvnd. Though a lot of people here are familiar with Linux Raspibian is based on Debian which is what most people here would be familiar with. You will have better luck and possibly a faster answer if you either ask in the Arch Linux ARM forum or the Unix stack exchange site which is larger than this one.